# Why does the first flow run on my newly initialized Corda node take so long?

Tags: initialization, corda, lag

When I start my Corda node (Azure VM 16gb ram, Postgres DB), why does it take so long to run the first flow? Regardless of the flow - finance flows, custom self-issuance flows, multi-party flows - why do the first set take so long to execute? Further, why do they all execute all at once?

My assumption is that the node is performing other activities under the hood after it's started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nodes are remote then it needs to set up SSL connection between the pair, this could cause the delay